# Images acting strange in Hugo

Tags: markdown, hugo

I am currently using Hugo to build a static website. I have the following folder structure:

```
content
└── en
    └── docs
        ├── software-practices
        │   ├── _index.md
        │   └── Git
        │       ├── _index.md
        │       └── branching
        │           ├── _index.md
        │           └── images
        │               └── git-branching.png
        └── ...
```

Within `content/en/docs/software-practices/Git/branching/_index.md` I have the following line:

`![Branching Diagram](images/git-branching.png)`

I expect this to render and display the specified image on the page. However, when I start the server for the first time with `hugo server`, the image doesn't render and the alternative text is displayed instead. Strangely enough, if I rename the `_index.md` file to something else, e.g., `myfile.md`, the image suddenly renders. It even renders when I change it back to `_index.md`. However if I restart the server, the error occurs again.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page that is named `index.md` is a 'leaf bundle'. A page that is named `_index.md` is the list page of a (sub)section, which is also called a 'branch bundle'. The issues you are experiencing is intended behavior.

Source: https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/

Answer (score 1):

When you browse to the page while using `hugo server`, does the URL end with a slash? This affects relative URLs like with this image, and I believe is probably where your problem lies.

The relative URL of `images/git-branching.png` is resolved as:

`/en/docs/software-practices/Git/branching` ->
`/en/docs/software-practices/Git/images/git-branching.png`

`/en/docs/software-practices/Git/branching/` ->
`/en/docs/software-practices/Git/branching/images/git-branching.png`

I encountered this problem myself with links in Hugo. Once the site is built, only the trailing slash URL loads; whereas when using `hugo server`, browsing to *either* URL loads the page, but the relative URLs it references can only be made to work in one or the other.

The solution we implemented at my last company was to run a program against the built version of our site that checks for broken links, as part of our Continuous Delivery pipeline. In our case, we chose [linkchecker](https://github.com/linkchecker/linkchecker). I don't know if this would detect broken image URLs, but if not, I'm sure there'd be a tool out there for it.

Regarding the server restart, I wonder if there is some browser caching going on. Try having the Chrome devtools open and ticking Network -> Disable cache.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. I found that if the .md file name starts with an underscore, the server doesn't render the image properly upon start. I don't know if this is intended behavior or not though.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue. I found that if the .md file name starts with an underscore, the server doesn't render the image properly upon start. Just naming it index.md seems to resolve all the issues (weird).

I don't know if this is intended behavior or simply a bug within Hugo.